# Friend Class across the Namespace not working in Xcode Cpp (macos dynamic library)

Tags: c++, macos, friend

classA.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "classC.h"

using namespace Bname;

namespace Aname
{
    class  A
    {
        friend class B;
    private:
        void Aclassmethod();
    };

}
```

classB.h:

```
#pragma once
namespace Bname
{
    class B
    {
    public:
        void Bclassmethod();
    };
}
```

classC.h:

```
#pragma once
namespace Bname
{
    class C
    {
    };
}
```

classA.cpp:

```
#include "classA.h"

void Aname::A::Aclassmethod()
{
}
```

classB.cpp

```
#include "classB.h"
#include "classA.h"

void Bname::B::Bclassmethod()
{
    Aname::A *vv = new Aname::A();
    vv->Aclassmethod();            **ERROR**// Aclassmethod is a private member of Aname::A
}
```

I try to compile the code for macos as dynamic library ,The code is Getting compiler error in Xcode cpp (Accessing private Member of class),But Its Properly Compiling without any error in Visual studio.

Comment: On a side note `using namespace Bname;` don't. You pull the whole namspace B into the global namespace. Rather add `using B::B;` in namespace A, or even just `friend class B::B:`.

Comment: I cant able to do that,because i am not included the classB.h in classA.h

Comment: That indicates you are doing something wrong: see answer below. And why are you including `classC.h` in `classA.h`? If you don't directly use it, don't include it.

Answer (score 2):

In classA.h, when you write `friend class B;`, there is no way for the compiler to know that you mean `Bname::B` and not any other B.
An unqualified B like here, will be assumed to belong to the namespace of your line, so the meaning of your line is actually `friend class Aname::B`.

So change that line to `friend class Bname::B` and you are (almost) good. Now you will get a complilation error because Bname::B is not seen from A. This can be solved by forward declaring Bname::B in the top of classA.h:

```
namespace Bname {
class B;
}
```

So to conclude, change classA.h to:

```
#pragma once
#include "classC.h"   // This doesn't seem necessary

namespace Bname
{
   class B;
}

namespace Aname
{
    class  A
    {
        friend class Bname::B;
    private:
        void Aclassmethod();
    };

}
```

Comment: haha, was just writing this at this moment. You were faster. and extra virtual +1 for the class C remark (welcome to stackoverflow. great first contribution)

Comment: Its working,Thanks for your quick response.